# Is it possbile to import a javascript program in python?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am working on a research project. Where few of the libraries are written in javascript. Is there any possibility to import a javascript program in python as a module and be able to use its functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Jiphy library. This should help you in achieving this.

pip install jiphy

Learn more about library. [jiphy Library](https://pypi.org/project/jiphy/)

[Example to use Javascript in python](https://gist.github.com/oakfang/f65e10dd10992045c968)

Comment: the author has no description on how to use his library do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you check the second link, it is described there how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to install the Naked module like so:

```sh
$ pip install Naked
```

After that you can use:

```py
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js

response = muterun_js('file.js')
if response.exitcode == 0:
  print(response.stdout)
else:
  sys.stderr.write(response.stderr)
```